# Tool to automatically extract sub-images that are inside an image: sub-images separated by whitespace

Tags: shell-script, software-rec, utilities, imagemagick, image-manipulation

Is there a tool/script which can extract images (save them as separate image files) inside an image, each sub-image is separated by whitespace?

This:

> [image]

Would result in 3x:

> [image]

[Image Source](https://pixabay.com/en/dawn-sun-mountain-landscape-190055/)

Comment: [This thread on the ImageMagick forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16041) is essentially the same question, but neither [segment_image](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/segment_image) nor [multicrop](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php) work on your example image. The techniques they use can probably be tweaked to work for you though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Imagemagick scripts multicrop or multicrop2 will work on your image to separate them into 3 new images. Optionally you can unrotate them. They are Unix bash shell scripts and require a Unix-like environment.  See my web site at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

You do not mention what OS you are using and if you have Imagemagick installed and what version that might be.

Comment: `Linux Mint 18.1` running `ImageMagick 6.8.9-9`, I'll have a look at your script. Thanks! btw

Comment: Very nice collection of scripts. Now in the case of not-too-long scripts, would you  mind perhaps also posting them here in addition to the link? Please keep in mind that this might mean that you are possibly making a copy under a different license though. It's only so that even should your link stop working that the script is still retained as part of the answer to this question.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the white border that is left surrounding the image?

Comment: Try the unrotate options or just use Imagemagick -shave or -chop